# Как можно сделать запрос в гугл через Python с возвратом результата

Tags: python, python-3.x, запрос

Как можно с помощью Python сделать запрос в гугл например "попкорн" и чтоб в cmd вывелось информация про "попкорн", пробовал через `data = urllib2.urlopen(https://www.google.com/search?q=попкорн)` и `document = lhtml.document_fromstring(data.read())` но ничего не вышло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для такой задачи нужно парсить страничку,нужно использовать такие либы как: bs4,requests,selenium и др.
Получать страничку по адресу *****[https://www.google.com/search?q=запрос](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81)*****

Потом либо брать первую ссылку и парсить её:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

либо если есть можно брать текст из такого окна:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так же можно использовать [api](https://habr.com/ru/post/421173/) гугла